# Simplifying inequality raised to the power of 2

Tags: inequality

I was trying to solve a problem related to inequality and I came across the following:

```
1 - x^2 ≥ 0
x^2 ≤ 1 
-1 ≤ x ≤ 1 <= how is this possible?!
```

I do not understand how x^2 ≤ 1 becomes -1 ≤ x ≤ 1. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: $x^2\leq1\implies|x|\leq1\implies-1\leq x\leq1$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$$

the product is positive if the factors are both positives or both negatives.

Answer (score 1):

$\quad$Assume $x^2\le1$.  To show $-1\le x \le 1,$  it helps to separate the cases $x>0$, $x=0$, and $x<0$,

because multiplying inequalities by a negative number changes the direction of the inequality.

Now if $x\gt0,$ then $x\le1$; otherwise, if $x>1,$ there would be a contradiction $x^2>x>1.$

If   $x<0$ then $x\ge-1$; otherwise, if $x\lt-1,$ there would be a contradiction $x^2\gt-x>1.$

Therefore $x^2\le1 \implies -1\le x\le1$.

$\quad$On the other hand, if $-1\le x\lt0,$ then $1\ge-x\gt x^2\gt0$,

and if $0\le x\le1$ then $0\le x^2\le x\le1$,

so $-1\le x \le 1\implies0\le x^2\le 1.$